# Why won't my Quantaray teleconverter, which fits my EOS3, mount on my Canon 60D?

Tags: canon, teleconverter, compatibility

I have a Quantary teleconverter that I can use on my Canon EOS3 film camera but it will not attach to my 60D body but it attaches to all my other Canon Lenses. I don't want to force it. It seems like the pins won't allow it to seat into the body. Could the difference be that it is a crop sensor body whereas my other cameras are full frame digital!?

Comment: I will go up to Levines Camera store.They are quite knowledgeable and will look over my problem. They would let me mount one with my lenses. They are about 40 miles north of me.The Quantaray is one of the oldest in my collection (around 1970's )and maybe I need to buy a branded more up to date unit. Thanks for your input dpolitt

Comment: Something isn't right here: Canon cameras and lenses in the 1970s used the older FD lens mount. FD lenses or teleconverters will not attach to *any* EOS body whether film, digital APS-C, or digital Full Frame. The EOS mount was not introduced until 1987.

Comment: Yeah I agree. The teleconverter will attach to the lenses but not to the digital body. I will probaby end up purchasing a new converter. I will check it out this weekend at the camera store. Thanks for your response.

Comment: But anything made pre-1987 will not fit any of your lenses either, nor the EOS 3. FD was a totally different mount.

Comment: Do you have any serial number for the converter? I guess even a photo could help to identify it. Preferably from both sides to show the camera and lens mounts.

Comment: @MichaelClark  no where in the question does it mention an FD mount.  Neither camera he mentions uses and FD mount.

Comment: @Alaskaman He does mention in his comments that the Quantaray teleconverter has been in his collection since the 1970s. The EF mount and the EOS system didn't exist until 1987. If he had a TC in the 1970s that fit Canon cameras and lenses it was the FD mount.

Answer (score 1):

The Canon 60D is compatible with both EF and EF-S lenses as it is an APS-C size crop sensor. A standard EF teleconverter will mount on a Canon 60D without a problem. I'm not sure that they are made, but if you were to find an EF-S specific teleconverter that would be an issue if you tried to mount it on a full frame camera such as the EOS 3.

In your situation I don't know of a reason why your teleconverter does not mount.

Note that canon branded teleconverters use the nomenclature extender.